# Puppeteer Memory snapshot failed

Tags: puppeteer, google-cloud-run

Running puppeteer on Google Cloud run in a container.

Was expecting to be able to scrape a site using puppeteer but I am receiving the following error:

```
�[32mINFO�[39m �[33m PuppeteerCrawler:�[39m Starting the crawl
�[31mERROR�[39m Memory snapshot failed.
```

I've increased the memory to 16GB on the cloud run instance but still encounter the same error.

I've set the following args but still run into the same issue

```
const crawler = new PuppeteerCrawler({
        // Here you can set options that are passed to the launchPuppeteer() function.
        launchContext: {
            launchOptions: {
                headless: true,
                args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-gpu', 'disable-dev-shm-usage', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
                executablePath: 'google-chrome-stable'
            },
        },
```

Its not clear to me if the memory snapshot process is part of puppeteer or chromium. Which is making this error difficult to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to use the base image

```
FROM node:16-bullseye-slim
```

when I changed to

```
FROM node:16-bullseye
```

It resolved the issue.

Here's the complete DockerFile

```
FROM node:16-bullseye

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y wget gnupg \
    && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst fonts-freefont-ttf libxss1 \
      --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /app
COPY index.js ./
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm ci --only=production

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```